# Will an iOS device fall back to 802.11a when 802.11n is unavailable?

Tags: wifi

I was told that iOS devices defaults to 802.11a which runs on 5 GHz band when 5 GHz 802.11n is not available. Have anyone experimented with that?

How does negotiation between access points and client devices work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wireless chipset samples all spectrums and chooses the frequency that has the highest potential speed with a joinable SSID and won't generally switch to a different network unless there are errors or a drop.

Since the protocols are different there isn't so much a negotiation as a decision tree which of the several channels to join.